# turn a multiple line of txt file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a multiple line of text like:

```
fischer morphy 1 - 0
carlsen alekhine 0 - 1-
kasparov capablanca 1/2 - 1/2
```

and I need a way to read the txt file, and turn it into a dictionary like this

```
    # match result dictionary
match_result = [ # dict name
    {
        "match": "1",           # match
        "wht_ply": "fischer",   # white player name
        "blck_ply": "morphy",   # black player name
        "wht_scr":"1",          # white player score
        "dash":"-",             # unused dash
        "blck_scr":"0"          # black player score
    },
```

so i can use

```
        for item in match_result:
        if item["wht_scr"] and item["blck_scr"] == "1/2":
            print("match",item["match"],"game between white player",item["wht_ply"],"and black player",item["blck_ply"],"ended up in draw")
```

and get the result of match that ended in draw

is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: but your file doesn't look like the dictionary you've posted.

Comment: Could you use a JSON file instead of text file? Or even a CSV file? What do you want to do?

Comment: please replace the image with the actual **text** of the data

Comment: i've replaced the image with the text

i need to use txt file in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a `.json` file, this way:

```
{
    '1': ['Fischer', 'Morphy', 1, 0],
    '2': ['Carlsen', 'Alekhine', 0, 1] # Did this match has never been disputed in reality, right?
}
```

---

The parsing would be done this way:

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'r+') as file:
    matches = json.load(file)
for i in matches.keys():
    print(f"Match {i}: {matches[i][0]} {matches[i][2]} - {matches[i][1]} {matches[i][3]}")
```

---

It is possible to parse a `.txt` file too, even if it's a bad practice to store datas this way. When I suggested to store a dictionary in a `.txt` file in a way similar to yours, one expert told me:

> Unless you want to reinvent the wheel, you should use a `.json` file

---

You can anyway `split` the lines this way:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n') # lines is a list of the lines of the file
dictionary: dict = {}
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    line = line.split(' ')
    dictionary[str(index)] = {
        "white": line[0],
        "black": line[1],
        "white score": line[2],
        "black score": line[4]
    }
```

Comment: the homework wants me to use txt file and not json 
but thanks anyway. I might learn json soon and this will be useful

Comment: Don't ask for homework on Stack Overflow! @Hauzan. Anyway I'll provide an answer for the .txt file too.

Comment: i just need to turn the txt into dictionary and i will do the rest

Comment: @Hauzan, I've edited my answer. I hope this will work. You should remove the minus sign after the second line, that's probably a typo.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer

however when i try to run it python say 

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I'll try it with my executor and your text file and I'll soon tell you what was wrong with my code. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: "black": line[1],
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Hauzan https://gist.github.com/FLAK-ZOSO/74054e070899035bb2187f1c10ca2008